# .htaccess effect the other url on file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url

I have recently create the .htaccess to rewrite the url for SEO friendly.
The url becomes working fine. But the url I assign will effect the url of other. 
The .htaccess file is shown in fig. When subject file runs. The url will be as class/physics When I click on any other file on subject page. Before changing url the login page url is login.php After changing the name of other file it also effects the login.php it appears like class/login.php which is annoying. Guide me to solve this problem.

```html
<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
</Files>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On 

#--exclude real directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#--and files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(\w+)$ ./subject.php?class=$1&subject=$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: the question is difficult to understand, can you give your URL and a destination URL?  what I can understand from the question is, you want http://example.com/subject.php?class=some&subject=thing => http://example.com/some/thing  am I correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have a problem with relative URLs. If on the `/class/physics` page (or URL) you have a *relative* link to `login.php` then this will naturally be relative to the `/class/` "directory" (as it appears on the client-side), so the resulting URL is `/class/login.php`, not `/login.php`, which appears to be your intention.

Ideally, you need to make your URLs root-relative (starting with a slash) eg. `/login.php`. (Or even absolute, with a scheme + hostname.)

Alternatively, as workaround you can use the `base` element in the `head` section to inform user-agents what the relative URL is relative to. For example, if these URLs are intended to be relative to the document root then:

```
<base href="http://example.com/">
```

Note, however, there are some caveats with the `base` tag. Notably if you are using internal anchors eg. `#top`, then this is now relative to the `base` URL. (And this breaks on IE6 without a hack.)

Your old URLs (ie. `/subject.php?class=abc&subject=abc`) all appear to be in the document root, so your relative links were not a problem.